# Touch events with Magic Mouse and iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, simulator, magic-mouse

I observe that with the iMac magic mouse, while using the iPhone simulator, if:

a) the active view has an object in the center of the iPhone screen which is capable of generating touch events, and
b) the iMac operator accidentally or otherwise drags their finger(s) across the magic mouse surface in a way which would normally be used for scrolling, that

the object in the center generates (bogus) mouse down and drag events.

If there is no such object in the center of the screen, there is no issue.

Is there a way to programmatically or otherwise disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with all Mac input devices with scroll functionality. If you do a two-fingered scroll up and down on a Macbook touch pad the same thing happens.

I believe this is more or less "intended", though it appears the touch up event is lost - so sometimes the interface gets stuck after a scroll gesture. I don't know of a way to programmatically disable this feature, unfortunately :-/

Comment: Thanks Ben, I was afraid of that.  However, if intended, I'm having difficulty finding the value in it.  Why not add a new event type? -- McP

Comment: Well, I think the event only occurs in the simulator, so a new event in UIKit wouldn't really be useful for programming apps (since  you're not targeting anything with a scroll wheel). It'd be cool if they'd just fix the simulator so it didn't respond to scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

Gesture-based scrolling the iOS simulator was disabled sometime around iOS 4 or the iPad, I believe. It would have conflicted with the giant, scrolling window of the iOS simulator running on smaller screens.