# I am thinking about buying the magic mouse but can I use it's multitouch capabilities for the iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

Can you use the magic mouse to use the iphone simulator, and get like more than just two fingers on the phone simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You'll be able to use the simulator but not more than two fingers. Simple like that :)

Edit: There might be some drawbacks

[Touch events with Magic Mouse and iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087797/touch-events-with-magic-mouse-and-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Really wish we could tell them to do that for us.

Comment: well, I'm sure that the integration is at least planned.

Comment: the more people that ask for something, the quicker it bubbles up the queue

Answer (score 1):

I've got a MacBookPro that has a multi-touch touchpad and it doesn't allow multi-touch in the iPhone simulator.  Sucks, doesn't it?

Comment: Entirely!!!!!!! I wish they came to their senses and made it easier for their programers...

Comment: There's only so far you can take it before your testing is too far removed from actual user experience. You can use the Option key to get your mouse to give you two touch points in the simulator for pinching and rotating, and you can use the Shift key to move the center of the two touches, e.g. to do a two-finger swipe or pan.